# How can i retrieve the row just entered in database in django

Tags: django, django-forms

I used this function to save data in Mysql

```
form.save()
```

Now i want to send the row back so that i can dynamically update the Table and append the row at Bottom. How can i retrieve that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you save data to MySQL using `form.save()` so you probably use `ModelForm`.
So ModelForm save method returns the instance of Model (row):

```
row = form.save()
```

More on this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method